# are anaconda prompt and command prompt same?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have recently installed anaconda and I have found that it comes with anaconda prompt. when I tried to install pip on my windows from its command prompt, it gave a fatal error

```
C:\Users\Windows 10>C:/Python38/Scripts/pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" '
```

So I tried to install pip using anaconda prompt and to my surprise, it got installed. I still don't know why my window's command prompt didn't work but more than that, can I use anaconda prompt for future use. Are the same? command prompt and anaconda prompt?

Comment: Can you try the same command with backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Comment: There is an issue on the pip GitHub here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5223

Comment: No, nothing is working. whenever I type a command in command prompt it does nothing, absolutely nothing